# cannot disable DEBUG level log from org.apache.kafka.common

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

I am using log4j 1.2.17 with the following configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=OFF
```

With configuration above, I had expected that we would not see DEBUG level logs from kafka 2.4.0 libraries that we are using. However, somehow I still see logs as below. I have also tried using log4j2 with the same properties file in my application, it is the same. How shall we disable DEBUG level logging from kafka client libraries?

```
06:59:40.995 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name join-latency
06:59:40.995 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name sync-latency
```

06

Comment: How did you add log4j2? How are you running this code?

Comment: i updated the maven dependency to use log4j2.  i ran the code using plain `java -cp ... -Dlog4j.configuration=file:..." ... command

Comment: That property is for log4j 1.x, not 2, though

Answer (score 2):

Create a logback.xml with below contents (within the Resources folder):

```
<configuration>

 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
 </appender>

 <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
 </root>
</configuration>
```